# Interesting Topic Ideas for Non-Linear Programming

Tags: algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, dynamic-programming

I am looking for interesting topics to follow with the following 4 topics

1. Dynamic programming,
2. Policy iteration algorithm,
3. Pontryagin maximum principle,
4. Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation.

For example, with the Dynamic Programming one, I could do a Car Racing. As seen in this photo [DP for Car Racing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS9gQ.png).
Obviously very simplified but what topics do you think would best demo each of the problems

Comment: Surely 4 is an example of 1?

Comment: Have a look on this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415617.